# c++ calling a variable produce seg fault [smartPointed object]

Tags: inheritance, segmentation-fault, smart-pointers

I m working on a project for neuronal simulation, I have a seg fault I cannot understand, neither with gdb. I m using SmartPointers

I have something like this:

```
class vehicle:enable_shar_from_this() {
   protected 
   double direction_;
   }

class car: public direction_ {
    friend class policeAgent;
    public:
    void change_direction(rnd);
    }

class policeAgent: enable_share... {
    public:
    std::vector<CarSmartPointer> cars ={};
    void close_the_street(rnd);
}

car::change_direction(rnd_num){
    OLD_direction=direction;
    direction+=direction+rnd_num;
    newCar=make_shared<CarSmartPointer>();
    arriving_cars.push_back(newCar);
    }

publicAgent::close_the_street(rnd_num){
    lastCar= cars.cend();
    for (myCar=cars.begin(); myCar!=lastCar; myCar++)
        {(*myCar)->change_direction(rnd_num);}

main{
auto sbirro makeshared<publicAgent>();
while (not cars.empty()){
sbirro->closeTheStreet()
}
}
```

all the variables are initialized in proper constructor, this programs runs for 100-150 cycle, then it segfaults!!
The segfault happen when assigni OLD_direction=direction
I tried to print 'direction' but segfault, I m sure it's there since I printed a line before
It doesn't happen at the end of the container. It s not the last car, but the second, which segFault

this is the backtrace, the program is huge and I m using OpenMP, but in this case it's not called at all.
I cannot debug step by step cause I m using a python interface and I ve the main.cpp on another computer and to initialize the whole program is many lines of code... I will do tomorrow.

```
Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

0x00007ffff6319675 in growth::GrowthCone::grow (this=0x0, rnd_engine=...)
    at /..my_folders../elements/GrowthCone.cpp:52

52          double store_angle=angle_;

```
gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6319675 in
growth::GrowthCone::grow(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long,
32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul,
2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&) (this=0x0,
rnd_engine=...)
at /..my_folders../elements/GrowthCone.cpp:52
#1  0x00007ffff631ce2e in growth::Neurite::update_growth_cones(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned
long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul,
2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&) (this=0x983700,
rnd_engine=...)
    at /..my_folders../elements/Neurite.cpp:58
#2  0x00007ffff631cd70 in
growth::Neurite::grow(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul,
624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul,
15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&) (this=0x983700, rnd_engine=...)
    at /..my_folders../elements/Neurite.cpp:44
#3  0x00007ffff631245d in
growth::Neuron::grow(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul,
624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul,
15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&) (this=0x724390, rnd_engine=...)
    at /..my_folders../elements/Neuron.cpp:120
#4  0x00007ffff630f37f in
_ZN6growth17SimulationManager8simulateERKNS_4TimeE._omp_fn.0(void) ()
    at /..my_folders../kernel/simulation_manager.cpp:110
#5  0x00007ffff535e15f in GOMP_parallel (fn=0x7ffff630f251
<_ZN6growth17SimulationManager8simulateERKNS_4TimeE._omp_fn.0(void)>,
data=0x7fffffffd010, num_threads=1, flags=0) at
/build/gcc/src/gcc/libgomp/parallel.c:168
#6  0x00007ffff630efeb in
growth::SimulationManager::simulate(growth::Time const&) (this=0x99b2b0,
t=...)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was modifying the container while looping, so it was an undefined behaviour.

Solution add a temp container to store new cars then insert in old container!